# Copy Button using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

please help me...I just want to create a copy button using `jquery` or `javascript` that will copy all signature on the white box.

[image]
if i clicked the copy signature.. the whole signature on the white box(`signature_gen`) will copy and if i used ctrl+v it will paste on the outlook..

here's my html code:

```
<div id="signature_gen" class="signature_gen">
  <table width="482" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="129" rowspan="3" align="center" valign="middle"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" width="114" height="114" /></td>
      <td width="2" rowspan="3" bgcolor="#999999"></td>
      <td colspan="8" align="left" valign="top"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="76" colspan="8" align="left" valign="top">
        <table width="340" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="10"></td>
            <td width="269">
            <div>
              <b><?php echo $fname; ?></b>
              <br />
              <?php echo $position; ?>
              <br />
              WeChat: <?php echo $wechatid; ?> | Skype: <?php echo $skypeid; ?> 
              <br />
              Mobile No.: +<?php echo $mobileid; ?> <?php echo $mobileid2; ?> <?php echo $mobileid3; ?> 
            </div>
            </td>
            <td width="10"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td height="10" colspan="10"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="18"></td>
      <td width="29"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/51talk/"><img src="images/fb.png" width="29" height="29" /></a></td>
      <td width="6"></td>
      <td width="29"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company-beta/3017837/"><img src="images/in.png" width="29" height="29" /></a></td>
      <td width="6"></td>
      <td width="29"><a href="https://twitter.com/51TalkPH"><img src="images/tw.png" width="29" height="29" /></a></td>
      <td width="6"></td>
      <td width="198"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/51talkph/"><img src="images/insta.png" width="30" height="30" /></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="10" align="center" valign="middle"><p class="footer"><div2><em>51Talk,an NYSE listed company, is a leading  online English teaching platform in the world.</em></div2></p></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="btn-section">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn-copy" value="Copy Signature" />
</div>
```

and my js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function copyToClipboard(elementId) {


  var aux = document.createElement("input");
  aux.setAttribute("value", document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML);
  document.body.appendChild(aux);
  aux.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");

  document.body.removeChild(aux);

}
</script>
```

but when i try to paste the code it goes like this:
[image]

i want to make it like this:
[image]

hope you can help me...

Comment: going to need to see some html for the page, essentially you need to select the p? tag get the text value and add it to the person's clipboard using that button

Comment: yes your right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#SignatureHtml").attr('data-clipboard-text', $("#Box").html());

        var clipboard = new Clipboard('.Btn');

        clipboard.on('success', function (e) {
            $("#Box").css("border-color", "blue");
            $("#PastSection").focus();

        });


    });
```

```css
.element {
        float: left;
    }

    #Box {
        width: 200px;
        height: 85px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- download plugin url : https://clipboardjs.com-->
    <!--best solution-->
    <script src="https://clipboardjs.com/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <div class="element" id="Box">
            <span>Test Text1</span>
            <br>
            <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" width="100" />
            <br>
            <b>Test Text2</b>
        </div>
        <div class="element">

            <textarea rows="6" cols="40" id="PastSection" placeholder="Ctrl+V"></textarea>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div>
        <button id="SignatureHtml" class="Btn" type="button" data-clipboard-text="">copy</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend adding an ID to :

```
<div id="message">
    <b><?php echo $fname; ?></b>
    <br />
    <?php echo $position; ?>
    <br />
    WeChat: <?php echo $wechatid; ?> | Skype: <?php echo $skypeid; ?> 
    <br />
    Mobile No.: +<?php echo $mobileid; ?> <?php echo $mobileid2; ?> 
    <?php echo $mobileid3; ?> 
</div>
```

You'll need to select the text using jQuery/Javascript then make the button trigger this:

```
function copyText(){
    var aux = document.createElement("input");
    aux.setAttribute("value", $("#message").text);
    document.body.appendChild(aux);
    aux.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

Something like that should work

and then on your button add `onclick="copyText()"`

Comment: put the id on the div that surrounds the text, or change the text to a P tag and put the id on that, then you'll only be selecting the text

Comment: Already did that.. when I used ctrl+v the code table are still pasting...

Comment: it doesn't reflect that in your code above however make sure you're selecting the right id, this should work.